# Fail with errors 'Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED'

Tags: transactions, error, bsc, pancakeswap, cryptoeconomics

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x41fcd1893c7500ae2ace0ab195bb0c9bbfcfefd05ad794707a65749d358da3df. I don't undestand why my transaction is failed. I fixed my fee limit at 1.500.000 and only 10% was used. If someone can help me ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Pancake: Transfer failed` error is usually thrown when the output token (that you ***swapped the `tokenIn` for***) cannot be transferred out.

It could be when the token contract is paused, or when it requires a KYC, and the PancakePair doesn't have the permissions to transfer it out.

> The output token cannot be transferred. There may be an issue with the
> output token. (https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-frontend/blob/1d29560fcba7652a2758e09626df4cc607077ab4/apps/web/src/utils/transactionErrorToUserReadableMessage.ts#L58)